# tidyr unnest, prefix column names with nested name during unnesting

Tags: r, tidyr, unnest

When running `unnest` on a `data.frame` is there a way to add the group name of nested item to the individual columns it contains (either as a suffix or prefix). Or does renaming have to be done manually via `rename`?

This is particularly relevant with 'unnesting' multiple groups that contain columns with the same names.

In the example below the `base` `aggregate` command does this well (eg. Petal.Length.mn), but I couldn't find an option to get `unnest` to do the same thing?

I'm using `nest` with `purrr::map` as I want the flexibility to mix functions, eg. calculate means and sd on a couple of variables and also run a t test to look at differences between them.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

msd_c <- function(x) c(mn = mean(x), sd = sd(x))
msd_df <- function(x) bind_rows(c(mn = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))

aggregate(cbind(Petal.Length, Petal.Width) ~ Species, 
          data = iris, FUN = msd_c)
#>      Species Petal.Length.mn Petal.Length.sd Petal.Width.mn Petal.Width.sd
#> 1     setosa       1.4620000       0.1736640      0.2460000      0.1053856
#> 2 versicolor       4.2600000       0.4699110      1.3260000      0.1977527
#> 3  virginica       5.5520000       0.5518947      2.0260000      0.2746501

iris %>% 
  select(Petal.Length:Species) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  tidyr::nest() %>% 
  mutate(
    Petal.Length = purrr::map(data, ~ msd_df(.$Petal.Length)),
    Petal.Width = purrr::map(data, ~ msd_df(.$Petal.Width)),
    Correlation = purrr::map(data, ~ broom::tidy(cor.test(.$Petal.Length, .$Petal.Width))),
  ) %>% 
  select(-data) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(c(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Correlation), names_repair = tidyr::tidyr_legacy)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 13
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>   Species    mn    sd   mn1   sd1 estimate statistic  p.value parameter conf.low
#>   <fct>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <int>    <dbl>
#> 1 setosa   1.46 0.174 0.246 0.105    0.332      2.44 1.86e- 2        48   0.0587
#> 2 versic~  4.26 0.470 1.33  0.198    0.787      8.83 1.27e-11        48   0.651 
#> 3 virgin~  5.55 0.552 2.03  0.275    0.322      2.36 2.25e- 2        48   0.0481
#> # ... with 3 more variables: conf.high <dbl>, method <chr>, alternative <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to this was somewhat obvious, use the `names_sep` option rather than the `names_repair` option. As quoted from the `nest` help menu under `names_sep`:

> If a string, the inner and outer names will be used together. In
>   nest(), the names of the new outer columns will be formed by pasting
>   together the outer and the inner column names, separated by names_sep.
>   In unnest(), the new inner names will have the outer names (+
>   names_sep) automatically stripped. This makes names_sep roughly
>   symmetric between nesting and unnesting.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

msd_c <- function(x) c(mn = mean(x), sd = sd(x))
msd_df <- function(x) bind_rows(c(mn = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))

iris %>% 
  select(Petal.Length:Species) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  tidyr::nest() %>% 
  mutate(
    Petal.Length = purrr::map(data, ~ msd_df(.$Petal.Length)),
    Petal.Width = purrr::map(data, ~ msd_df(.$Petal.Width)),
    Correlation = purrr::map(data, ~ broom::tidy(cor.test(.$Petal.Length, .$Petal.Width))),
  ) %>% 
  select(-data) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(c(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Correlation), names_sep = ".")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 13
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>   Species Petal.Length.mn Petal.Length.sd Petal.Width.mn Petal.Width.sd
#>   <fct>             <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 setosa             1.46           0.174          0.246          0.105
#> 2 versic~            4.26           0.470          1.33           0.198
#> 3 virgin~            5.55           0.552          2.03           0.275
#> # ... with 8 more variables: Correlation.estimate <dbl>,
#> #   Correlation.statistic <dbl>, Correlation.p.value <dbl>,
#> #   Correlation.parameter <int>, Correlation.conf.low <dbl>,
#> #   Correlation.conf.high <dbl>, Correlation.method <chr>,
#> #   Correlation.alternative <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To apply multiple functions to multiple columns I would use `summarise_at`/`mutate_at` instead of nesting and unnesting data.

For example, in this case we can do :

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(Petal.Length:Petal.Width), list(mn = mean, sd = sd))


#  Species    Petal.Length_mn Petal.Width_mn Petal.Length_sd Petal.Width_sd
#  <fct>                <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>
#1 setosa                1.46          0.246           0.174          0.105
#2 versicolor            4.26          1.33            0.470          0.198
#3 virginica             5.55          2.03            0.552          0.275
```

This automatically adds a prefix to column names which we are applying the function to. Also, this is equivalent `dplyr` version of `aggregate` function you tried.

Also note that `summarise_at` will soon be replaced with `across` in upcoming version of `dplyr`.

Comment: Thanks. This works if you want the same functions to be applied to all variables (as in my `aggregate` example). But it doesn't work if you want to mix (complex) functions - hence why I was using `purrr::map`. I couldn't add in the 'Ratio' column above or add the output from a t.test for example.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. As far as I see you are passing the same function i.e `msd_c` or `msd_df` for multiple columns. As far as `Ratio` column is concerned you can just create that column and pass it to same function. `iris %>% 
  mutate(Ratio = Petal.Length/Petal.Width) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(Petal.Length,Petal.Width, Ratio), list(mn = mean, sd = sd))`

Comment: Sorry I didn't come up with a good example. Have edited the question to replace 'Ratio' with 'Correlation' which makes it more obvious that the functions are quite different.

Comment: @JWilliman Well, you can do `iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Petal.Length:Petal.Width), list(mn = mean, sd = sd)) %>%
  mutate(Correlation = list(broom::tidy(cor.test(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)))) %>%
  slice(1L) %>%
  unnest_wider(Correlation)` in that case. I still don't get the purpose of `nest` and `unnest`. Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setNames` like below. It is a little bit wordy, but it seems like you plan to specify each function for each column, this may be of interest.

```
iris %>% 
  select(Petal.Length:Species) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  tidyr::nest() %>% 
  mutate(
    Petal.Length = purrr::map(data, ~ msd_df(.x$Petal.Length) %>%
                                setNames(paste0("Petal.Length.", names(.)))),
    Petal.Width = purrr::map(data, ~ msd_df(.$Petal.Width) %>%
                                setNames(paste0("Petal.Width.", names(.)))),
    Ratio = purrr::map(data, ~ msd_df(.$Petal.Length/.$Petal.Width) %>%
                               setNames(paste0("Ratio.", names(.))))
  ) %>% 
  select(-data) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(c(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Ratio))
# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   Species [3]
  Species    Petal.Length.mn Petal.Length.sd Petal.Width.mn Petal.Width.sd Ratio.mn Ratio.sd
  <fct>                <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 setosa                1.46           0.174          0.246          0.105     6.91    2.85 
2 versicolor            4.26           0.470          1.33           0.198     3.24    0.312
3 virginica             5.55           0.552          2.03           0.275     2.78    0.407
```

Or modify your function to allow it being able to modify the column name like this.

```
msd_df_name <- function(x, name){
  bind_rows(c(mn = mean(x), sd = sd(x))) %>%
    setNames(paste0(name, ".", names(.)))
}

iris %>% 
  select(Petal.Length:Species) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  tidyr::nest() %>% 
  mutate(
    Petal.Length = purrr::map(data, ~ msd_df_name(.x$Petal.Length, "Petal.Length")),
    Petal.Width = purrr::map(data, ~ msd_df_name(.$Petal.Width, "Petal.Width")),
    Ratio = purrr::map(data, ~ msd_df_name(.$Petal.Length/.$Petal.Width, "Ratio"))
  ) %>% 
  select(-data) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(c(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Ratio))
```

Comment: Thank you. This probably is the way to go. I just wonder if I was missing something in the `names.repair` argument of `unnest`. It says that you can pass a function (for custom name repair), or 'a purrr-style anonymous function' but I wasn't sure how to write one that would capture the group name.

Comment: @JWilliman I don't know how to use `names.repair`, either. It would be great if someone can share their insights.

Comment: Adding the group name seems to me to be the most intuitive way of avoiding duplicate names IMO, but perhaps it isn't so easy to implement. I'll see if someone comes up with a solution using it, otherwise I'll tick your answer.

Comment: I discovered that I'd overlooked the `names_sep` option which does exactly what I wanted. Regarding the `names_repair` option this is passed to `vctrs::vec_as_names`